# Visual Studio Code support emmet?

Tags: visual-studio, sass, emmet

I install Visual studio code and i want to use emmet in HTML or Sass file, but when i type something like `bgc` for background-color in scss file and press tab nothing happened!

[image]

How I can enable Emmet inside vsc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Install the Twig pack extension and reload the window. You'll have to temporarily change the extension of the file you're working on to html for emmet to work, which can be achieved with the tab key.